# min max functions for a list of string is returning on what basis

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to explore kotlin but when i came across list of strings like below.

- I tried min and max functions with it.
- And i initially thought it will give compile time error but i didn't get that.
- And when i print `min` i got `a555585887996669` as output which is the longest word in array.

```
val list = listOf<String>("a555585887996669","abtfcr6cr","abcde","abcd")
   println(list.min()) //a555585887996669
```

- I need to know on what basis it is returning this value
- why min and max is supported to list of strings

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`min()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/min.html) and [`max()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max.html) extension functions operate on anything that can be compared.  That includes numeric types, but also on anything that implements the [`Comparable`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparable/) interface, which is the standard way for objects to implement a natural ordering.

In this case, [`String`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/) implements `Comparable`; it uses [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) (which is roughly the order of words in a dictionary), comparing characters pairwise until it finds a difference, or until one String ends.  So for example "a" < "abc" < "b".

Collection ordering in Kotlin is explained [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collection-ordering.html).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this docu:
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/min.html

Since String implements comparable, min will return the smallest value based on alpha-numeric sorting.

For eval. array by string length:

```
list.minBy { it -> it.length };
```